# Why can't I get an item from a Collection and store it in a variable?

Tags: vba

I have a Collection which I use to have a `String -> MailItem` map. I fill the map, and when I find a duplicate key I want to read the item in the Collection.

This seems so easy, but I spent more than an hour trying to figure out why I can't assign a Collection item to a local variable. (see `PROBLEM` in code below)

> `oMailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)` "Object variable or With block variable not set"
>
> `Set oMailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)` "Object required"

The other `cMails(cMailKey)` form gives the same error. Moving the Dim around doesn't make any difference. `cMails` must be available because it's used earlier in the method. *Note the `Debug.Print` line just before this statement, **that works***. What am I missing?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Public cMails As Collection
 
Public Sub GetOutlookAttachments()
    Set cMails = New Collection

    Dim oStore As Store
    For Each oStore In Session.Stores
        If oStore.DisplayName = "Outlook Data File" Then
            ProcessFolder oStore.GetRootFolder()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
 
Private Sub ProcessFolder(oFolder As Folder)
    Debug.Print oFolder.FolderPath
    ProcessItems oFolder.Items

    Dim oSubFolder As Folder
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.Folders
        ProcessFolder oSubFolder ' recurse
    Next
End Sub
 
Private Sub ProcessItems(oItems As Items)
    Dim oItem As Object
    For Each oItem In oItems
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf oItem Is MailItem Then
            Dim oMail As MailItem
            Set oMail = oItem
            Dim cMailKey As String
            cMailKey = oMail.ConversationID & "-" & oMail.ConversationIndex
            If Not Contains(cMails, cMailKey) Then
                cMails.Add oMail.Subject, cMailKey
            Else
                Debug.Print cMails.Item(cMailKey)
                Dim oMailOther As MailItem
 PROBLEM        oMailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)
                Debug.Print cMailKey & ": " & oMailOther.Subject
            End If
        ElseIf TypeOf oItem Is MeetingItem Then
            ' ignore
        Else
            Debug.Print "oItem Is a " & TypeName(oItem)
        End If
    Next oItem
End Sub

Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim obj As Variant
    On Error GoTo err
    Contains = True
    obj = col(key)
    Exit Function
err:
    Contains = False
End Function
```

*I also tried to replicate similar `Add` and `Item` calls elsewhere and **it works***.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Set cMails = New Collection
    
    Dim cMailKey As String
    cMailKey = "hello"
    cMails.Add Session.Stores.Item(1), cMailKey
    
    Debug.Print cMails(cMailKey)
    Dim oStore As Store
    Set oStore = cMails(cMailKey)
    Debug.Print oStore.DisplayName
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` instead of `Collection`. Dictionary has native `.Exists()` method, so you won't need `Function Contains()`.

Comment: @omegastripes I know, but that part works fine, otherwise it wouldn't get to the `PROBLEM` line. I don't want additional dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider `Scripting.Dictionary` to be a problematic dependency - it would require work for it *not* to be available on the target machine.

Comment: ```Set oMailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)```?

Comment: @Comintern I have to tick a checkbox in the References window, hence it is an external dependency, i.e. non-default. I agree though, it would be hard not to find it on a machine :)

Comment: You only have to add a reference if you're early binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it. The collection `cMails` you are creating is a collection of `Strings`, not of mail objects; however, `oMailOther` is declared as an `Object` of type `MailItem`.

In your assignment without the `Set` keyword, VB complains that your want to assign something to an object (left-hand side) and should use the `Set` keyword. Now, with the `Set` keyword, VB complains that the right-hand side is not an object...

To make `cMails` into a colection of mail items, change the `Add` statement as follows:

```
cMails.Add oMail, cMailKey
```

(i.e. you don't add `oMail.Subject` but the whole `oMail` object.)

Now use the `Set` keyword in `Set oMailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)` and everything works fine.

Comment: How did you see this: "is a collection of strings"? (other than noticing the `.Subject` at `.Add`).

Comment: I set a Watch on `oMail` and inspected the item(s) and saw they were strings, as others noted through analysis.

Comment: It's so weird that it can't say "MailItem required", like most sane languages would (InvalidCastException, ClassCastException).

Comment: That is because `MailItem` is a type of `Object` and the compiler stops when it finds the assignment involves a non-`Object`. The message "MailItem requied" could be given when you try to assign an `Object` of the wrong type to an `Object` of type `MailItem`. Compilers are so logical...

Answer (score 2):

`oMailOther` is a `MailItem`, so without a question you must use `Set` what assigning it to a variable:

```
Set oMailOther = cMails(cMailKey)
```

However your `cMails` collection does not contain a `MailItem` object. It contains only subjects (that are strings as opposed to objects) that you previously added with `cMails.Add oMail.Subject, cMailKey`.

Apparently you meant `cMails.Add oMail, cMailKey`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't how you are *retrieving* the items, it's how you're *adding* them:

```
If Not Contains(cMails, cMailKey) Then
    cMails.Add oMail.Subject, cMailKey
Else
```

`Collection.Add`'s first parameter is what you are storing in the collection - in this case the Subject. When you are trying to retrieve items from the collection here...

```
Debug.Print cMails.Item(cMailKey)
Dim oMailOther As MailItem
MailOther = cMails.Item(cMailKey)
Debug.Print cMailKey & ": " & oMailOther.Subject
```

...you are trying to retrieve the object itself.  The `Debug.Print` works because you have a Collection filled with Strings.

If you need a collection of MailItem, you need to fill it like this:

```
cMails.Add oMail, cMailKey
```